# How split arraylist to multiple lists by specific property object Java8 in one line

Tags: java, java-8

Suppose I have

```
private String userId;
private String email;
private AWSRegion region;
private String total;
List<Prop> all = new ArrayList<>
all.add(new Prop("aaa", "dddd", "EU", total1));
all.add(new Prop("aaa1", "dddd", "US", tota2l));
all.add(new Prop("aaa2", "dddd", "AU", tota2l));
all.add(new Prop("aaa3", "dddd", "AU", tota3l));
all.add(new Prop("aaa3", "dddd", "EU", tota4l));....a lot of regions
```

I want in one line `java8` to have list of lists by property "AWSRegion"

some think like....but not to run it as "filter predicate" because I have many of regions...

```
List<Prop> users = all.stream().filter(u -> u.getRegeion() == AWSRegion.ASIA_SIDNEY).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

RESULT should be list of lists:

```
LIST : {sublist1-AU , sublist2-US, sublist3-EU....,etc'}
```

thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `groupingBy` to get a `Map<AWSRegion,List<Prop>>` and then get the values of that `Map`:

```
Collection<List<Prop>> groups =
    all.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Prop::getRegion))
       .values();
```

If the output should be a `List`, add an extra step:

```
List<List<Prop>> groups = new ArrayList<>(
    all.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Prop::getRegion))
       .values());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a map with `<AWSRegion, List<Prop>` by grouping your list by region:

```
Map<AWSRegion, List<Prop>> regionMap = all.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Prop::getRegion, Collectors.toList()));
```

If you want that as a list, then you can simply call:

```
List<List<Prop>> lists = new ArrayList<>(regionMap.values());
```